# Getting error 'es: unknown configuration property Suppress_Type_Name'

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent-bit

If not using 'Suppress_Type_Name', I am getting the following error:

[error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=400 URI=/_bulk, response:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"},"status":400}

Then using 'Suppress_Type_Name' in the following elasticsearch conf:

output-elasticsearch.conf: |
[OUTPUT]
Name                es
Match               *
Host                logging.host
Port                9000
HTTP_User           someuser
HTTP_Passwd         somepassword
Logstash_Format     On
Replace_Dots        On
Retry_Limit         False
tls                 On
tls.verify          False
Type                _doc
index               someindex
Logstash_Prefix     someprefix
Suppress_Type_Name  On

the fluent-bit pods fail to start:

Fluent Bit v1.4.1

[error] [config] es: unknown configuration property 'Suppress_Type_Name'. The following properties are allowed: index, type, http_user, http_passwd, aws_auth, aws_region, logstash_format, logstash_prefix, logstash_prefix_key, logstash_dateformat, time_key, time_key_format, include_tag_key, tag_key, buffer_size, path, pipeline, generate_id, replace_dots, current_time_index, trace_output, and trace_error.

I have not tried anything yet as the 'Suppress_Type_Name' should be the solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Fluent Bit to the latest v2.0.10 resolves the issue.